# Access Angular route scope property $resolve within controller instead of view

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

AngularJS 1.5.0 brings the $resolve property, designed to make it easier to pass the ngRoute resolve data into the view without the need to create a controller for directives. This property also works for regular views. So this works:

```
(function() {
  function ConfigureRoutes($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'test.html',
        controller: 'TestController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
          'stuff': ['$q', function($q) {
            return $q.when([
              { id: 1, name: 'John' },
              { id: 2, name: 'Jake' }
            ]);
          }]
        });
      }
      app.config(['$routeProvider', ConfigureRoutes]);
})();


<pre>{{ $resolve.stuff | json }}</pre>
```

However, there are times when I have several resolve functions I want to pass into the controller to mutate before using in the view. Currently I do something like:

```
when('/test', {
  ...
  resolve: {
    'stuff_1': ...
    'stuff_2': ...
  }
});

app.controller('StuffController', ['stuff_1', 'stuff_2', function(stuff_1, stuff_2) {
  this.stuff_1 = stuff_1;
  this.stuff_2 = stuff_2;
}]);
```

Is there a way of accessing this new $resolve property without having to access the parameters individually? I've tried:

```
app.controller('StuffController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  this.stuff_1 = $scope.$resolve.stuff_1; // $scope.$resolve == undefined
}]);

app.controller('StuffController', ['$resolve', function($resolve) {
  this.stuff_1 = $resolve.stuff_1; // injector error
}]);
```

EDIT:

For those who may find this in the future, you **can** access this $resolve object a different way in your controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($route) {
  this.$resolve = $route.current.locals;
});
```

So the decision was made to not attach `$resolve` before the controller is instantiated.

The decision was also made not to made `$resolve` and injectable. This can be achieved using `$q.all()` as a single resolve function, like so:

```
function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/',
    controller: 'TestController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: 'test.html',
    resolve: {
      $resolve: function($q) {
        return $q.all({
          local_1: $q.when(),
          local_2: $q.when()
        });
      }
    });
}
```

Or if you want to have a forked version, see the PRs at
($scope.$resolve before controller)[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14135]

($resolve as injectable)
[https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14136]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is apparently a delay between when the controller is invoked and when the `$resolve` property is placed on scope.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("test", function($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = $scope;
    console.log("test controller")
    //console.log(vm);
    console.log("$resolve=",$scope.$resolve);  //Undefined
    $timeout(function() {
         console.log("timeout $resolve");
         console.log("$resolve=",$scope.$resolve); //Defined
    });
});
```

Using `$timeout`, the values resolve.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4urrnsLu/).

---

### Example with `$watch`

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("test", function($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;
    console.log("test controller")
    console.log(vm);
    console.log("$resolve=", $scope.$resolve); //Undefined
    $scope.$watch("$resolve", function(value) {
         console.log("watch $resolve");
         console.log(value); //Defined
    });
});
```

Using `$watch`, the values resolve.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hr1rkfhx/).

---

### Review of Source Code

In [ngView.js Line #273](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L273), the controller is instantiated.

In [ngView.js Line #280](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L280), the `$resolve` property is put on scope.

This is a **bug**. There is no reason the `$resolve` property can't be put on scope **before** the controller is instantiated.

---

### From GitHub:

### feat(ngView): reference resolved locals in scope [#13400](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/13400)

All the resolves for a route are now attached to the route's local scope,
as the property whose name is given by the `resolveAs` property on the
route definition.

If `resolveAs` is not specified it defaults to `$resolve`.

This will make it easier to use `ngRoute`, by being able to reference all
the resolve values for the route, directly on the scope, rather than having
to implement a controller just to copy the resolves across manually.

For example, rather than

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  resolve: {
    item1: ($http) => $http.get(...),
    item2: ($http) => $http.get(...)
  },
  template: '<my-app item1="vm.item1" item2="vm.item2"></my-app>',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  controller: ['item1', 'item2', function(item1, item2) {
    this.item1 = item1;
    this.item2 = item2;
  }]
});
```

one can now do

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  resolve: {
    item1: ($http) => $http.get(...),
    item2: ($http) => $http.get(...)
  },
  template: '<my-app item1="$resolve.item1" item2="$resolve.item2"></my-app>'
});
```

Comment: I knew there was something screwy here - the docs, as you show, point to using this for directives declared within the `$routeProvider` config, and I couldn't find any examples of using it in a typical controller-view scenario like I want. I wish I could add a few more upvotes for the work you did digging into the source. I glanced there but didn't dive in enough, I guess. I'll file a bug. It'd be nice if it was available to the injector as simply `$resolve` so I don't need to inject the whole `$scope`. It seems odd to set `this.$resolve = $scope.$resolve` when `this` becomes the scope...

Comment: It would be easy to add `$resolve` to the list of injected locals for the controller. It's a good idea. Include that  suggestion when you file your [new AngularJS Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/new).

Comment: Sadly, see [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96dwgjea/1/) - using $timeout the value will propagate to the console but still not to the view

Comment: See my example with `$watch`.

Comment: I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14134) and a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14135) to fix the timing issue. I also have code ready that would allow `$resolve` or `resolveAs` to be injected in the controller - just waiting on an answer about whether they want me to combine or separate the two PRs. Thanks for your help @georgeawg

Comment: I have also now submitted a separate [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14136) for injecting `$resolve` or `resolveAs` into the controller.

Comment: For anyone coming here in the future, they've decided not to fix the bug (they don't see it as such, since it wasn't technically designed for that purpose).